# Rightmove deliveryPointId does not match up with Royal Mail "CSV PAF.CSV" file

Tags: rm, paf

I have obtained a particular property's deliveryPointId from one of their pages.  I then tried to match it up with its correct address from the PAF file but find that it matches a property in a completely different part of the country.

Surely the RM "deliveryPointId" and the PAF file "UDPRN" are supposed to refer to the same thing?

Does anybody know if there's anything that can be done with the RM deliveryPointId to make it match with the correct property on the PAF file?